# Use Savon SOAP to investigate parameters

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

In order to do some investigative and debugging work, I would like to find out about the required and optional methods for a SOAP with WSDL.

In that WSDL, all required and optional parameters foor each SOAP action, as well as their type and form, are described.

Is there a way to extract these inside [Savon](https://github.com/rubiii/savon)?

Comment: This is really old, but for posterity: you can do this with the latest version of Savon (version 3). See the documentation (http://savonrb.com/version3.html) and [a related StackOverflow answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319426/how-to-get-the-list-of-inputs-for-a-particular-operation-in-savon-gem/17325141).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No -- you would need to use something like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/). :)

Comment: note that there is a "Pro" version, but you can still download an opensource version -- the Pro version is expensive.