# How to get the list of inputs for a particular operation in savon gem

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, wsdl, savon

Is there way to get the list of inputs(arguments) for a particular operation from a wsdl file in savon gem?

https://github.com/savonrb/savon

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the latest version of Savon (version 3):

```
client = Savon.new('your_wsdl_url')
op = client.operation('yourServiceName', 'yourPortName', :yourOperationName)
op.example_body
```

See the version 3 documentation for more information: http://savonrb.com/version3.html. This page also provides instructions for installing this version.

Comment: I'm aware that the question is a truism, but will you know any other stable way to do it?